# JSON STRING TO HASHMAP JSONSIMPLE

Tags: java, json

I have a **JSONString**:

```
<i>{1={"id":"1","description":"Red","Objects":{"doors":4,"number":4},"life":100}}</i>
```

How put this JSONString in a hashmap with `JSONSimple`?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

This code is used from the JSON-simple's wiki page at http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_1_-_Convenient_way:_Use_JSONValue

```
String s="[{1={"id":"1","description":"Red","Objects":   {"doors":4,"number":4},"life":100}}]";
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
```